# Wait for the already subscribed Observable

Tags: android, rx-java

I make a call to a server with subscribing and update the view of `Activity1` with result:

```
//from within Activity1
xxx = fetch.byId(id)
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Model>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Model model) {
          //update view with the model
        }
    });
```

All this should happen invisibly to the user (no progress dialogs etc.).

What I want more is to handle a click on `Activity1`: when clicked, I must wait (show progress dialog) for the `xxx` to receive the `model` and then start an `Activity2` (which needs the `model` value to be presented). If the click happened after the `xxx` finished then I don't have to wait (because it's already done) and start the `Activity2` right away.

How can I elegantly wait for the already subscribed Observable?

Comment: `If the click happened after the xxx finished then I don't have to wait (because it's already done) and start the Activity2 right away`. I still don't know at this part: If `xxx` finished, you already go to `Activity2` => there are no way to click in `Activity1` ?

Comment: Everything happens in Activity1, Activity2 has no meaning for this question and is just an example of action.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by utilizing the [`zip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator. It will emit an item only when all zipped observables emitted, ie the data is loaded and user clicked a button.

```
fetch.byId(id)
        .zipWith(RxView.clicks(button)
                     .doOnNext(click -> showLoading()), // when user clicks the button, show your progress dialog
                (model, click) -> model // when both model is loaded and button is clicked, pass only the model forward
        )
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Model>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Model model) {
                //update view with the model
                startActivity2()
            }
        });
```

Comment: I would prefer `combineLatest` over `zip`, as that's able to work for multiple clicks. If you need it to work just once, it's still more efficient to do `fetch.byId(id).combineLatest(RxView.clicks(button)...).take(1).subscribe(...)` as zip would buffer all clicks during fetching.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, but the an easy one, would be using [AsyncSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/AsyncSubject.html).

```
AsyncSubject<Model> async = AsyncSubject.create();
fetch.byId(id).subscribe(async);
xxx = async.asObservable();
xxx.subscribe(this.subscriber);
```

Then you can just chain things you want to do with `doOnSubscribe()` and maybe `toCompletable()`.

```
xxx.toCompletable()
   .doOnSubscribe(this::showProgress)
   .subscribe(this::goToActivity2, this::displayError);
```

Comment: actually this should work but this can be achieved even without Subjects